Attributes of MapServer WFS service all stay NULL
I did an update on my MapServer and database and now in QGIS all attributes of the updated WFS stay NULL. The WFS works fine in our web application. Just it is not showing any attribute data in QGIS.

layer specification:
LAYER
    NAME            "wijk_admin_2023"
    GROUP           "admin"
    INCLUDE         "connection_cdf.inc"
    DATA            "geom FROM cbs_wfs.wijken_2023 USING srid=3857 USING UNIQUE wijkcode"
    TYPE            POLYGON
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:3857"
    END

    EXTENT     373852 6577254 804561 7086146

    METADATA
      "wfs_title"           "wijk_admin_2023"
      "wfs_group_title"     "admin"
      "wfs_abstract"        "CBS WIJKEN 2023"
      "wfs_enable_request"  "*"
      "wfs_srs"             "EPSG:3857"
      "wfs_featureid"       "fid"

      "srsName"             "EPSG:3857"
      "gml_featureid"       "fid"
      "gml_include_items"   "all"
      "gml_default_items"   "all"
      "gml_types"           "auto"
    END
END


If you have a MapServer service that isn't following the layer object metadata attributes, then it is a bug and you should report it.

QGIS client shouldn't be a factor here in what is returned by default in the WFS service, so it's difficult to comprehend how it can work outside of QGIS, but not inside QGIS.  Can you use the QGIS debugger to see what requests are made by QGIS and post those requests and results in the question to better understand the issue.

After 2 days of trial and error updating mapserver to the newest version, qgis to the newest THE PROBLEM is that the newer mapserver for the following combination returns nothing. 2*all is nothing apperently.
I removed  "gml_default_items"   "all" and qgis showed me all attribute data again.
"gml_include_items"   "all"
"gml_default_items"   "all"   <-- remove this

Or another option that worked but now all data is always returned which might not what you want to have.
"gml_mandatory_items"   "all"

should this be an issue / ticket of mapserver?

Write mail to the mapserver-users mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/mapserver-users and ask.
